# Cannot assign a value of type 'MDLMaterialProperty?!' to a value of type 'Int'

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I have updated my Xcode 6.4 project into Xcode 7 and it has this problem...

```
class func preparationForSave(text_country: NSDictionary){
    let dataArray = text_country["countries"] as! NSArray;

    for item in dataArray {
        var it: Int = 0
        if (item["parentId"] == NSNull()){
            it = 0
        }else{
            it = item["parentId"]
        }
        Country.saveCountry(item["id"] as! Int, title: item["title"] as! String, parentId: it)
    }
}
```

it has error here: `item["id"] as! Int`
and says: Cannot assign a value of type 'MDLMaterialProperty?!' to a value of type 'Int'

It was working on Xcode 6.4...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a weird bug in XCode 7 which causes error about "MDLMaterialProperty?!" to pop up when types mismatch or variables weren't unwrapped.

Try this code (fixed in 2 lines):

```
class A {
    class func preparationForSave(text_country: NSDictionary){
        let dataArray = text_country["countries"] as! NSArray;

        for item in dataArray {
            var it: Int = 0
            if (item["parentId"] == nil) {  // item["parentId"] is of type X? - compare it with nil
                it = 0
            }else{
                it = item["parentId"] as! Int  // note that we're force converting to Int (might cause runtime error), better use: if it = item["parentId"] as? Int { ....} else { .. handle error .. }
            }
            Country.saveCountry(item["id"] as! Int, title: item["title"] as! String, parentId: it)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer!  Also, you may run into this when you have complex object hierarchies.  You have to call out and cast each step in the tree.  If you try to get fancy and combine lines, it'll throw the same error and fail every time.   i.e.   if buh["foo"]!["bar"]! as? NSDictionary   .. will throw the error. so you have to declare variables for each step along the way... Lame.  Only seeing this in 7.2.